# installation of HyperV on Dell Power Edge 2950 geniii

Tags: hyper-v-server-2016

Good day,

Would you please tell me if I can install HyperV server 2016 on Dell Power Edge 2950.

Your response will be Highly appreciated.

Regards,

Bob

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because dead end of life hardware platform.

Answer (score 1):

yes,

but if you are stuck on boot : windows logo is stuck on the screen.

Then it's because your BIOS version is higher than 1.5.1.

So downgrade BIOS version to 1.5.1

Respectfully.

Julien